# Problems with RegularGridInterpolator (Scipy) (Python)

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

Im having trouble using scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolant.More precisely, i cant make extrapolations with the interpolating function of the output. In the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html) says that if 'fill value' is None, the values out of the grid are extrapolated, but its seems not working. I want to interpolate linearly, I see other functions that extrapolate but with other methods (nearest neighbor, or a predefined value).

Here is an example with dummy data (not the arrays that im working but the case is the same)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator

x = np.array([11,22,33,44,55,66,77])
y = np.array([101,102,103,104,105,106,107])
z = np.random.rand(7,7)

x_new = np.array([1,12,23,34,45,56,67])
y_new = np.array([101,102,103,104,105,106,107])

interpolant_function = RegularGridInterpolator((x,y),z, fill_value = None)
result = interpolant_function((x_new,y_new))
```

This code raises the following error

```
    raise ValueError("One of the requested xi is out of bounds "
ValueError: One of the requested xi is out of bounds in dimension 0
```

Im stucked since few days, also if anyone knows another function to do the same and works well im glad to hear it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to add “bounds_error=False”.

```
interpolant_function = RegularGridInterpolator((x,y),z, bounds_error=False, fill_value = None)
```

Comment: thanks buddy, I owe you a few beers hahaha

Comment: For me, this does not work but that might be due to the histogram input. Should the histogram hold 0 or nan outside the data range?